# Any documentation for GTK engine murrine?

Tags: gtk, themes

I am new to the GTK theming. I have seen lots of themes designed with murrine and want to create my own but I haven't got any idea of how to use this engine.
The question is are there any manuals and how-to's related to murrine engine?

Answer (score 2):

They are unlikely to be written, as theme engines only apply to GTK 2, and no later versions.

If you are new to GTK theming then you should investigate CSS and the code for some of the existing CSS themes, especially the built-in Adwaita theme.

Comment: I am already know CSS, but are there any tutorials for GTK3 theming (except one at the developers.gnome.org)?